# How to Upload Files from a Raspberry Pi to a File Sharing/Transfer website

Tags: file-sharing, pi-b+

I have a Raspberry Pi B+ hooked up to my router at home, I can currently access it over the internet using weaved. How do I transfer files from a hard drive connected to the Raspberry Pi to somewhere like https://www.wetransfer.com without using something like the Midori Web Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your cloud storage provider provides a binary package for the RPi's ARM architecture or source code for one, you may be out of luck. If they provide an API, you may be able to code something yourself.

I would suggest using a provider that supports Linux natively, or using any of the many file transfer options available natively on the RPi such as `scp` or `rsync`. Alternately, you could just email the file(s) from the RPi as an attachment.

[Edit] If you're trying to move/copy a file from the RPi at home to your laptop on an outside network, you have several options:

1. Interactive file transfer from laptop: You could have the laptop "phone home" periodically and connect to your RPi and copy the file using `scp` or any of the many file-transfer programs that support it.
2. Automatic/on-demand sync from laptop: You could have the laptop "phone home" and synchronize files using `rsync`, `unison` over ssh, or something like [bittorrent sync](https://www.getsync.com/how-it-works) in a more automated manner. This would allow you to set up a 'sync' folder hierarchy and sync the contents with your laptop automatically.
3. Access laptop from RPi: Depending on your laptop OS (since you mention Samba, I assume it's linux, but could be Mac), you could run a service such as `ssh` to enable all of the above in the reverse direction. Of course, security issues abound, and your laptop might wind up behind a firewall that renders it unreachable. I've found originating transfers from my laptop to be far simpler and reliable.
4. External hosting: You could set up and outside server using [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) some other hosting provider and have the RPi and laptop push/pull files from there as needed. (I run a small EC2 instance, and it costs somewhere between $15-$23 per month, depending on storage and uptime for a small Debian linux server.) This would be more like the file-sending service you alluded to in that the server is the "always there" transfer point. You might install something like [owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) for this.

There are many (many) other options. One challenge you may face, depending on specifics of your setting, is *locating* the RPi at your home or your laptop on the road. If the IP address of either changes regularly, you probably need to utilize some sort of dynamic dyns service to allow automatic updating of the current IP address in DNS. [noip](https://www.noip.com/free) is a popular service for this.

Due diligence mandates that I point out that this is not a particularly RPi-specific topic and should probably be moved to another SE site... leaving one to wonder why exactly this one exists.

Comment: My goal is to upload a file from the Pi to my laptop, I could use something like Samba, but my laptop is outside of my home network. using weaved I can control the pi from my laptop but not transfer files between them

Comment: I'm not familiar with Weaved, but I am familiar with synchronizing between a variety of computers, including the RPi. I'm understanding that your laptop is the one moving around and that your RPi stays at home. Do you have access to your RPi from outside? By what means? Is it OK if the transfer is initiated by the laptop and not the RPi? If you're using ssh, you could set up rsync to have your laptop "phone home" and sync periodically, or fetch on demand. I do this to backup my laptop files while on the road. I'll edit my answer to summarize some options.